# Time picker shows wrong time iphone sdk

Tags: ios, datepicker, picker, timepicker

I have time picker in my app. I'm showing timePicker.date and the time is wrong.
NSLog is

```
 NSLog (@"date : %@",[timePicker.date description]);
```

log is like date: 2012-02-07 17:00:01 +0000

i think that problem is in timezone

in ViewDidLoad i have this code

```
timePicker.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
timePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

but it isn't working...

Can somebody help me to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the time picker is correctly applying time zone, but you're logging it using  GMT rather than local time so that it just looks wrong. If you want to display the time returned from your time picker using local time, use NSDate's descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale: method, or use the NSDateFormatter class to get complete control over how your date is displayed.

Comment: Thank you! i'm using NSDateFormatter